# Group x axis labels

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I need to group (and show) labels of X axis of a grahp, but still showing all single labels.

This is the code I actually use, and its a normal column2d graph:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
        var myChart = new FusionCharts({
            type: "column2d",
            renderAt: "chart",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            dataFormat: "json",
            dataSource: {
                "chart": {
                    "animation": 0,
                    "caption": "Graph title",
                    "xAxisName": "Performance",
                    "baseFontColor": "#000000",
                },
                "data": [
                                                {
                        "label": "351-08",
                        "value": "91"
                    },
                                            {
                        "label": "351-09",
                        "value": "90"
                    },
                                            {
                        "label": "351-10",
                        "value": "94"
                    },
                                            {
                        "label": "351-01",
                        "value": "99"
                    },
                                            {
                        "label": "351-07",
                        "value": "92"
                    },
                                            {
                        "label": "351-06",
                        "value": "81"
                    },
                                        ],
                "trendlines": [
                    {
                        "line": [
                            {
                                "startvalue": "82",
                                "color": "#ff3333",
                                "thickness": "5",
                                "valueOnRight": "1",
                                "displayvalue": "Average"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }).render();
    });
```

What I need is showing another label on X axis that groups labels.
For example:

- Group 1: [label1, label2];
- Group 2: [label3, label4, label5];
- Group 3: [label6];

**UPDATED**

I attached an image of what I need.
As you can see I need another labels line ("Fattore1", "Fattore2" and "Fattore3") that group other labels.

[image]

Comment: May be you should elaborate more, unable to understand where is x and y ? and what is the ogic behind grouping . May be post the final response you arelooking for

Comment: @SanyamGoel I attached the image to explain better what I need

Comment: @Giacomo Masseroni Chiaro This may be currently not possible with FusionCharts, however, they released time-series charts in which grouping is there, also you can use annotations for giving textual information, but they can create a custom chart for you drop a mail to support@fusioncharts.com

Annotations link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/annotations